# How to write mysql query to sort data by month starting from current month

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have one table with one column named 'created_at'. Now i want to all records group by month and order by month start from current month.

Here is the MySQL query I've written so far:

```
SELECT count(id),MONTH(created_at) as month 
FROM `perks` 
GROUP BY created_at 
ORDER BY MONTH(created_at)
```

and out put is:
[image: out put]

I need month august(8) first as it is current month then 9,10,11,12,1,2... so on.

Can any buddy help to resolve this issue?

Comment: Your code pls so that we can help you.

Comment: Super difficult to write a query without any data schema.  And one named column does not suffice. No tables, no data... no query. Also: when you edit your question to include such detail (including both sample data and expected output), also include what you've tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: @JayminNoob, Thanks.
Here is my sql query.
SELECT count(id),MONTH(created_at) as month FROM `perks` GROUP BY created_at ORDER BY MONTH(created_at)

Comment: @DavidMakogon some stress in your life at the moment? Last few times you've been commenting on lower quality noob questions you've come across a bit abrupt..

Comment: @CaiusJard, Let me explain in one simple example.
Suppose i have one table restaurant and want to show all visited customer month wise (It may be past year also). Also month should be start from current month.

Comment: So, for all time past and future you want to know how busy that table is monthly..I.e. You can say "if it's august, the busiest table is the window one"

Answer (score 1):

As jaymin indicated you need to group by the month, not the time

```
GROUP BY MONTH(created_at)
```

Also if there are times before now that need excluding, use a where clause:

```
WHERE created_at > current_date()
```

If your data includes dates next year, you'll probably need to `group by year(created_at), month(created_at)` and order by this too, unless you don't care that next years august is rolled into this years august etc

If the intention is to roll everything together, and have the months go round in a full circle starting with the current month, you'll need to:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN MONTH(created_at) >= MONTH(current_date()) THEN 1 ELSE 2, MONTH(created_at)
```

Comment: exactly :) Agreed

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
GROUP BY MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
```

Comment: @CaiusJard, Your solutions will not work. GROUP BY MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) will return data of current month only and where date > now will return data have date greater than today. i need old data also.